# VirtualBox VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED opening Windows 10 partition/vmdk

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, virtualbox

I'm trying to virtualize my physical Boot Camp partition, so I can do small Windows tasks from Mac without restarting. I followed mostly [this tutorial](https://kindlevsmac.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/how-to-run-windows-7-bootcamp-in-virtualbox/) but also read others.

But now when I try to launch the VM it prompts this: `VD: error VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED opening image file`

[image]

Any idea what could I try?

Comment: Did you try: *...disabling the use of the new async I/O code... done by ticking "Use host I/O cache" for the SATA (and SCSI) controllers...*?

Comment: That was it! It works now! If you want to include it as an answer I'll .. ?

Comment: OK I will write a short answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was (or obviously still is in VirtualBox 5?) a [known bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7251) of VirtualBox 3 which should have been fixed in ***4.0.0***!

The workaround is disabling the use of the new async I/O code... done by ticking "Use host I/O cache" for the SATA (and SCSI) controllers.

Comment: I never had this problem until I upgraded my host OS from Mavericks to El Capitan.  Then suddenly my VMs stopped booting. Problem persisted through a subsequent VirtualBox upgrade from 4 to 5—but this workaround solved it: thanks!

Comment: I am on VirtualBox 6.0.12 and getting this. The workaround here doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tried this on VirtualBox 6.1 and it still failed.
Could this have to do with the harddisc file is on another drive than the Virtualbox?  I normally do not have issues with this, however this is a .vhdx file which was created and running fine in Hyper-V and that one can NOT use harddisc from shared drives, and so I was thinking this could be related, however not sure